# Evaluate $3\cdot 7 + 5\cdot 10 + 7\cdot 13 +\dots+ 25\cdot 40 + 27\cdot 43$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate(get the value) Where argument of Σ is quadratic

$$3\cdot 7+5\cdot 10+7\cdot 13+\dots+25\cdot 40+27\cdot 43$$

Our professor gave this problem to us and told us to do it. We will have a quiz based on this problem, but I have no idea how to do it properly.

I know it keep goes like $(n\cdot y) + (n+2)(y+3) + (n+4)(y+6)+\dots$ 
But I think I need to form a sigma notation to solve it.

Comment: just a thinking..looks like you have a base term (3*7) and adding terms of (3+(2*i))*(7+(3*i))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$3,5,7 \to (2n+1)$

$7, 10, 13 \to (3n+4)$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{13} (2n+1)(3n+4) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{13} (6n^2 + 11n + 4) = 6\sum_\limits{n=1}^{13} n^2 + 11\sum_\limits{n=1}^{13}n + \sum_\limits{n=1}^{13}4$

$6 (\frac 16)(2(13)+1)(13+1)(13) + 11(\frac 12)(13)(13+1) + 4(13)$